# Jquery is not defined in HTML form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I keep getting this error. To solve it I have tried to load the Jquery library before my script, and ofcourse the other way around too.

My html currently looks like this:

```
  <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="pageContent" data-step='init' class="ui-widget">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="search">Handelsnaam</label>
        <input id="search" type="text" autocomplete="off" name="query" placeholder="Zoek op handelsnaam" class="form-control">
        <small id="searchHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Vul uw handelsnaam in...</small>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="handelsnaam">Handelsnaam</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="handelsnaam" name="handelsnaam" placeholder="Handelsnaam">
        <label for="straat">Straat</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="straat" placeholder="Straat">
        <label for="huisnummer">Huisnummer</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="huisnummer" placeholder="Huisnummer">
        <label for="huisnummertoevoeging">Huisnummertoevoeging</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="huisnummertoevoeging" placeholder="Huisnummertoevoeging">
        <label for="postcode">Postcode</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="postcode" placeholder="Postcode">
        <label for="plaats">Plaats</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="plaats" placeholder="Plaats">
        <label for="achternaam">Achternaam</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="achternaam" placeholder="Achternaam">
        <label for="opmerking">Opmerking</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="opmerking" placeholder="Opmerking">

        <input id="btntest" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="window.location.href = 'https://jewebsite.com/bedank-pagina?companyName=' + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('handelsnaam').value) + '&CPLastname=' + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('achternaam').value) + '&EXTRAOPMERKING=' + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('opmerking').value)" />
        </div>

    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js" ></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

My script.js file starts like :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
```

The exact errrors i get are :

```
jquery-ui.min.js:17 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

Comment: You included jquery-ui, but not jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include jQuery itself:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js" ></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```